# New Like Button Social Text

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Is there anyway to delete the new social text showing on our Like button?  It is maessing with the layout of our website and we are actually looking at just deleting it from all pages unless we can figure out how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the text "Be the first of your friends to like this." ?

Try

> Use the "button_count" layout. On the settings page this is "Button
>   with counter"

- http://www.sourcecoast.com/forums/jfbconnect/jfbconnect-joomla-25-support/4917-remove-be-the-first-of-your-friends-to-like-this
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-simple-facebook-connect-remove-text-beside-like-button